# How to substitute a string variable in a pattern search

Tags: regex, tcl

In TCL, I'm trying to pattern search by using regular expression. It's working while using a direct pattern search, but not if I use a variable for the pattern.

For example:

```
set str "this is actual string to search the pattern"
set pat "the"

regexp {the} $str val
regexp {$pat} $str val1

puts $val;  # it's working
puts $val1; # it's not working, showing error
```

How to substitute a string variable in a pattern search, I have even used `[...]` but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can go with

```
regexp $pat $str val
```

The braces prevented substitution, so you were matching the literal string "$pat" against your data string.

If you have metacharacters together with a variable substitution in the pattern, as in

```
if {[regexp -nocase \s$name\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+) $str val val1]} …
```

you need to prevent one substitution (backslash substitution) while allowing the other. This can be done with

```
if {[regexp -nocase [subst -nobackslashes {\s$name\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+)}] $str val val1]} …
```

(the switch can be shortened to `-nob`) but `subst` can be tricky. It’s easier to get the following right:

```
if {[regexp -nocase [format {\s%s\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+)} $name] $str val val1]} …
```

Note in both cases that braces are used to prevent all substitution, and then `subst` or `format` is used to rewrite the desired element in the string.

It’s a good idea to try out the pattern in an interactive shell like

```
% format {\s%s\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+)} $name
\sthe\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+)
```

That way, one can verify that the pattern looks alright before it is plugged into `regexp` and tested against data.

Documentation:
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: thank you, that's working but i suppose to use with metacharacters to search the lines from another file. here the statement is `if {[regexp -nocase \s$name\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+) $str val val1]}`. previously i mentioned as if {[regexp -nocase {\s$name\s\w+\s\w+\s(\d+)} $str val val1]}. Finally your solution is working but not with metacharacters for this condition